# Why can low-rep users cancel a gold hammer dup vote?

Tags: support, closed-questions, dupehammer

I'm curious about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564921/vb-net-datarecieved-not-firing).  I selected [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907490/serialport-not-receiving-any-data) as the duplicate and, since I have a gold badge in the [vb.net] tag, that instantly closed the question.

The OP did not take this well, as is common, and railed for a while about it in his question.  Ultimately posted the exact same answer.  A rather poor one compared to the dup, the Q+A is pretty useless.

What stunned me is that he re-opened the question all by himself.  Is this supposed to be normal?  There is no record of it in the post history, my close vote disappeared entirely.  Can't say I'm thrilled about it.

Comment: Are you sure you closed it? Because you don't see it anywhere closed in the timeline: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29564921/timeline If someone close a question you see this in the timeline e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29770583/timeline (<- See the "state")

Comment: I don't think this is the same question. If you really closed something as duplicate, perhaps they deleted it and reposted it and so you think it was reopened?

Comment: They seem to have posted duplicate questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562920/vb-net-serial-datarecieved-not-firing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564921/vb-net-datarecieved-not-firing

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Or look into your profile under activity-> votes: http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant?tab=votes If you voted to close the question and it's deleted

Comment: Looks like this has been taken care of.

Comment: That user is my new hero. He complained in the comments about people not using SO as it was intended while posting the same question 2-3 times

Comment: I have to add that I just received an e-mail from that user (I have edited their rant about duplicates out of one of their answers). I won't get into much detail about the content of the message, and will only say it ended with *"You come in weeks after the fact to ramble about a situation you knew nothing about [...]. This community is going to crap, and people like you are the reason. Get over yourself."*. Moderation team, you may be interested to know about this. I don't think the user has the slightest idea of the way the site works -- nor do they care.

Comment: He wasted 3 days of his life looking for the solution that was handed to him on a silver platter the day he asked it.  Hard to admit you did something boneheaded, even harder to stop being one :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oops, never mind, it appears the OP asked the question at least twice.  The one I hammered is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562920/vb-net-serial-datarecieved-not-firing), it was re-opened normally by 5 SO-user votes.

Ugh.

Comment: This question should be deleted, and I have flagged is as such, since it is an EXACT duplicate of this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564921/vb-net-datarecieved-not-firing

Comment: Well, it is an exact duplicate of the one I hammered with.  Ugh.

Comment: Regardless, the dupe is closed and pointing to the correct dupe. Since this one can't be closed as a dupe of that one and closing it as a dupe of the real dupe.... my god, I've gone cross-eyed.

Comment: I know the feeling :)

Comment: I think I got it sorted out. I don't know.

Comment: I think you made a dupe circle, @BilltheLizard; I can't vote to delete either one because "other questions are linked as duplicates", each of which points to the other. Not that this is any way an urgent matter, but I'd think one of them should be removed.

Comment: @Josh, I'm pretty sure that was the intent.